# Vote for Super User Moderator [poll]

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-nomination

As the Super User semi-private beta comes to an end this coming Tuesday, we need to elect a final community moderator for the site.

Remember, we’re looking for a good moderator; someone who is above all

- patient and fair
- leads by example
- shows respect for their fellow users in their actions and words

I've taken an informal poll from all the SU mods, and we have these three nominees. Please examine the candidates’ user pages to get a sense of what kind of moderator they might make.

I don't like poll questions but I am making an exception in this case on meta. <s>Question is closed to prevent any new answers from being added.</s> The [closed] designation was too intimidating, I think, so I removed it.

**Please don't add any new answers.**

---

**Please vote for the candidate you think would make the best Super User moderator**

Comment: and yes this is an experiment. It's only one factor we will use to make a decision, the voting here will not wholly determine the outcome.

Comment: Now *this* is how you run a poll! FWIW, i support Troggy - he loves technology.

Comment: In case anyone wants to reference prior discussions about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/superuser-com-moderator-nomination http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/use-meta-as-a-moderator-gauge

Comment: Hmm, judging by questions answered, Diago is a windows guy, Troggy is into macs and hardware, and Ivo knows about apps..

Comment: @john That is a pretty good analysis based on questions/answers. You are correct in my interest being in macs/hardware. I have a lot of windows knowledge also, but currently relocated for the time being and only have os x and vista installs with me. I like to verify as much as I can personally.

Comment: I am with Troggy on this one. I really enjoy SuperUser and the current team is doing well. I feel honored to be considered.

Comment: @John Interestingly I do answer a lot of Windows and Mac questions since I own both. I also run some Linux boxes however on the latter too I am far from being an expert. However I do try and answer questions around these platforms when I can.

Comment: My linux knowledge is mainly in Ubuntu at this time. I have interest in systems administration, currently developing/programming .NET software for a company, and used to be in computer support/technician.

Comment: @Diago: Sorry, I was a bit too keen to pigeonhole you there.  I just found it interesting that the three nominees seemed to have somewhat different areas of expertise.

Comment: @John - Not offended in anyway. Just wanted to mention it since I try and keep an open mind around the various technologies, and love playing. :)

Comment: We really need a way to make questions like this one "sticky".  As much as I hate forums with 15 sticky posts at the top, there are times when it's useful.

Comment: Why not encourage people to add more candidates, especially since you are only using it as one factor?  Seems to me that if the users run this thing, like you say in the FAQ, that you'd want more, not less input from users on mods.  "Remember, Super User is run by you!"

Comment: @Joel -- it's stuck to the announcements at the top.  How much stickier do you want it to be?

Comment: Hey Jeff, how come you can ask questions without one of the required tags on it? (support, discussion, bug, feature-request, ...)

Comment: me :)

Comment: @Jeff: I think Brad was forced to include one of the required tags when he edited the post. Perhaps an edit should be forced to include a required tag only if the post already has one?

Comment: "Only one factor", huh? I guess that's me then :D

Comment: [This was originally posted on MSE (then MSO, the only meta), and was migrated here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14417/134300). I have cleared the migration metadata to prevent it from being automatically deleted for being closed (by the RemoveRejectedMigrations logic).

Answer (score 43):

Diago

https://superuser.com/users/3981/diago

Comment: From what I've seen on MSO, Diago is a very good choice.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have as many best of/must have/subjective type questions asked to his name.

Comment: Why doesn't Diago have the ♦?

Comment: @Lucas: That's what this whole question is about - who gets to wear ♦ on SU

Comment: @random - I try and avoid these questions with a plague. I dislike questions that are best of solely because they almost always turn into arguments. However I do look at them objectively from an aspect if they are usefull to the OP with no ill intent.

Comment: Because you've not asked those type of subjective and populist questions, you've gotten at least one upvote.

Comment: Diago is a cool guy and have agreed with many of his answers. Having mods located around different parts of the globe/time zones is great too. He has got my vote if community would rather see him become a mod.

Comment: @Troggy Thanks very much. You do very well yourself however :)

Comment: +1 for this 123 ( 123 to fill the 15 chars needed :-/ )

Comment: Does it make it any easier if I also think Diago deserves it?

Comment: @Ivo - Now who's flattered?

Comment: +1     for       this

Comment: Ok the evidence Diago is probably the better mod: http://superuser.com/questions/23258/restore-windows-xp-tablet-edition-on-acer-travelmate-c110/23320#23320 You edit the post, I answer it

Answer (score 32):

Troggy

https://superuser.com/users/2553/troggy

Comment: I feel SU will attract a lot of duplicate/poor worded questions even more so than the other sites. We need understanding and patience when handling these questions to direct people to the correct information. SU will grow very quickly and will need many mods to keep things in order.

Comment: Good speech Troggy :)

Comment: Also, mods need to be able to admit when they are wrong and be able to support other mod's decisions. It should be a humbling experience and not a power trip.

Comment: I realize that this isn't that fair of a characteristic to judge someone by, but there's nothing in Troggy's profile that links him to a real person. No picture, no website (google.com is used instead), vague location, fake birthday, etc. Troggy - if you're elected/selected, would you be willing to reduce your anonymity?

Comment: Maybe I really am 89? haha. Yes, I thought someone might criticize that. I will change some of that information so people can contact/know more about me if I am selected.

Comment: Fake people need moderation too! **Vote Troggy - he might be a bot!**

Comment: I am not sure I could come up with anything more random than the mod TheTXI's location: "A place of lush green fields full of happy magical ponies"

Answer (score 26):

Ivo

https://superuser.com/users/1548/ivo

Comment: :O I feel flattered!

Comment: I enjoyed your advice on your blog Ivo: "PS: you NEVER, I repeat NEVER get a girlfriend if your first words are: I like video games… The only worst thing you could say is that you like Star Trek or guys!"  I got a few friends I will pass that advice onto.

Comment: Haha, perhaps I shouldn't spend as much time on Superuser so I actually have time to write new posts. Plus I always like to think my advice is useful (so much for modesty)

Comment: @Ivo Well, You have been rather helpful to people on SU, so not all your time has gone to waste.